# Robot - Move Mouse to Position with RGB Value

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm currently using the Java Robot class to move mouse to coordinates:

```
Robot bot = new Robot();

bot.mouseMove(x, y);
```

The issue is that I need to move mouse to a coordinate in order to click on a specific button in popup window and the window can move from one position to another each time it appears (it is not always in the same position). (In my specific case I'm sending `Ctrl + P` to Notepad and then clicking the "Print" button in popup window).

I was thinking of retrieving the RGB value of the button I want to click via:

```
Color color = bot.getPixelColor( MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x 
                    , MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y);


System.out.println(color.getRGB());
```

and then somehow moving the mouse to the position with the given RGB value but I am not exactly sure how to implement this.

*Or is there an alternative solution that I did not think of?*

Thanks!

**Update:**

I realized that moving mouse using RGB value may not be the best solution bec if there's more than one coordinate with the same RGB value it could detect the wrong point.. is there a way around this?

Comment: I would go for getting the window position using JNA, then with that position calculate which would be the position of the button or at least have a lesser space to use mouseMove to find that pixel.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I thought was a kind of screen scan looking for the desired color, and then you have to decide to where the mouse pointer has to move.

But scanning pixel by pixel would take a lot of time, so you may want to skip some pixels. Here's the solution I've come out:

```
//Look for some color on Screen, skiping or not a value of pixels
    public static void scanScreen(Color matchColor, int skipPixel){

        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();

            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            double width = screenSize.getWidth();
            double height = screenSize.getHeight();

            //Scan the screen pixel by pixel
            for(int pixelX = 0; pixelX<= width;pixelX = pixelX + skipPixel){
                for(int pixelY = 0; pixelY<=height;pixelY = pixelY + skipPixel){


                    Color currentColor = r.getPixelColor(pixelX, pixelY);
                    System.out.println(pixelX+","+pixelY+": " + currentColor.getRGB());
                    if(matchColor.getRGB()==currentColor.getRGB()){
                        //TODO Do whatever you want with the location found

                        System.out.println("Found color: " + matchColor.getRGB() + " at "+ pixelX + ","+pixelY);
                    }


                }
            }
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
            Color c = new Color(-1972490);
            scanScreen(c, 100);
    }
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!

EDIT1: You can use this solution along with what Jorge Campos suggested in his comment.